# Strange login flow in Microsoft Products

Tags: usability, login, workflow

When I open OneDrive, OneNote or other Microsoft software, I press the Log In button and it displays a form with a field to enter ONLY email. When I press Next, I land on a standard login form with email field completed.
Why not display the login form directly when I land to onedrive.com?

Here are some screenshots of this behavior:

First step when I press login:

[image: FIRST STEP]

And then the login form after entering email:

[image: SECOND STEP]

This seems so strange; can somebody explain this flow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest in this way they try to increase conversion rate, making first step very easy.

When users bump form, they often struggle fill it or leave it. One-field form looks very simple, so more people agree to fill it.

When they switched to the next step, they tend to continue process. Research in behavioral economics show, people tend to be consistent with their previous behavior. So if they started filling the form, they likely continue doing this, i.e. they confirm theirs choice in this way.

Comment: Agreed. Also possible for microsoft to use the space to show, as they do in this case, an ad for another one of their products. Chances are their research showed that even if it isn't something to purchase, just informational, if it's a pretty picture and the colors match certain criteria, it'll make the user logging in happier and more likely to do...whatever it is they're going to do.